# Find distance between list's elements

Tags: f#

I have a list of numbers and want to get the list of distances between the numbers.
For example:

```
[1; 3; 8; 10; 12] → [2; 5; 2; 2]
```

Here is my code:

```
let rec diffs lst acc =
  match List.length lst > 1 with
  | true ->
      let first = List.head lst
      let second = List.head (List.tail lst)
      diffs (List.tail lst) (List.append acc [second - first])
  | false -> acc
```

I am just wondering if there is any better solution ?

Comment: Probably better for codereview.se  but there is definitely room for improvement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A translation to something more idiomatic

```
let rec diffs lst =
  match lst with
  | head::head2::tail -> (head2-head)::(diffs (head2::tail)
  | _ -> []
```

Answer (score 8):

Probably the most straightforward way using what F# gives you out of the box:

```
let diffs =
   Seq.pairwise
   >> Seq.map (fun (a,b) -> b - a)
   >> List.ofSeq
```

In general, calls to `List.head`, `tail` or `append`, particularly if they appear in a recursive function, are mild code smells in my book. They usually mean that the function can be written in a different, more streamlined way (case in point - @John's approach in the other answer, which you can easier map to the code you started with).

One more tip - you extend your accumulator using `(List.append acc [second - first])`, which is very wasteful. You need to traverse and copy the entire list to add elements at the end. The usual pattern is to add the elements from the head `((second - first) :: acc)` and reverse the accumulator when you return.